# Twisted: Close connection after connectTCP without losing other connections

Tags: python, tcp, twisted

I'm new to Twisted, and I'm trying to figure out how to implement the following.
I have a server, which takes a message from a client.  This server, however sends the message from the client to another server after it receives it.
So it looks something like:

```
Client --->   Server1  --->   Server2
```

So Server1 in essence, acts as both a server and a client.  However, after Server1 sends information to Server2, I want to disconnect Server1 from Server2.  I'm not sure how I can do this.

What I have now working is the Client sending information to Server1.  I then modify the input a bit, then do `reactor.connectTCP()` which succesfully connects and sends information to Server2.  My trouble is how can I close the connection without having to shut down Server1 completely.  I tried using `transport.loseConnection( )` but this shuts down Server1 when it disconnects from Server2.

I'm thinking about using `reactor.spawnProcess()` in some way, but I can't get it to work.  From what I see, when I close the connection, it closes the process so if I can do connectTCP with another process, it shouldn't affect other processes.

Here is my code

```
import time, datetime
import re
from twisted.internet import stdio, reactor, protocol
from twisted.protocols import basic

result = 'The AT message is unavailable (no previous talk with client)'

class DataForwardingProtocol(protocol.Protocol):
    def __init__(self):
        self.output = None
        self.normalizeNewlines = False

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        if self.normalizeNewlines:
            data = re.sub(r"(\r\n|\n)", "\r\n", data)
        if self.output:
            self.output.write(data)

class StdioProxyProtocol(DataForwardingProtocol):
    global result
    def connectionMade(self):
        inputForwarder = DataForwardingProtocol()
        inputForwarder.output = self.transport
        inputForwarder.normalizeNewlines = True
        stdioWrapper = stdio.StandardIO(inputForwarder)
        self.output = stdioWrapper
        self.transport.write(result)
        self.transport.loseConnection( )

class StdioProxyFactory(protocol.ClientFactory):
    protocol = StdioProxyProtocol

    def clientConnectionLost(self, transport, reason):
        reactor.stop()

    def clientConnectionFailed(self, transport, reason):
        print reason.getErrorMessage()
        reactor.stop()

class EchoProtocol(basic.LineReceiver):

    def dataReceived(self, line):
      #Do stuff with the input sent from the client.  This is irrelevant to my problem.
                #UPDATE OTHER SERVERS
                reactor.connectTCP('localhost', 12771, StdioProxyFactory())   

class EchoServerFactory(protocol.ServerFactory):
    protocol = EchoProtocol

if __name__ == "__main__":
    port = 12770
    reactor.listenTCP(port, EchoServerFactory( ))
    reactor.run( )
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your Server1 is shutting down because you call `reactor.stop()` in your factory's `clientConnectionLost()` method, not because of the `transport.loseConnection()` call. You probably don't want to shut the whole reactor down as soon as the first outgoing connection is lost.